# Google Sheets | Index Match AND Max Date combined formula

Tags: google-sheets, maxdate, index-match

I am trying to find a formula to use in Google Sheets that would combine an Index Match and a Max Date formula. Attached a screenshot for reference.

Index would be 'Phase' column C
Match would be 'ID Number' column B
With an additional step of selecting the most recent/Max date of 'Last Modified Date' column A

The end result should be the same as the example 'Current Phase'  column D.

[Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH3sF.png)

//copy of Array Data

/*Current Phase is the desired end result

Last Modified Date |ID Number|               |Phase|                          |*Current Phase|
2/26/2022       165432               Welcome                         Health Check
3/1/2022        165432               Adoption                        Health Check
3/2/2022        165432               Health Check                    Health Check
2/26/2022       165432               Prep                            Health Check
2/26/2022       165432               Close                           Health Check
6/21/2022       412356               Welcome                         Adoption
6/23/2022       412356               Adoption                        Adoption
2/26/2022       412356               Health Check                    Adoption
2/26/2022       412356               Prep                            Adoption
2/26/2022       412356               Close                           Adoption

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

The following formula should create the desired behaviour:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER($C$2:$C,$A$2:$A=MAX(FILTER($A$2:$A,$B$2:$B=$B2))),1,1)
```

Note that if multiple phases are tied for most recent, this will return only the first (i.e. lowest row number).

### Explanation

The inner `=FILTER` selects only those rows from column A where column B has the same ID as the current row being evaluated. Then, the `=MAX` gets the most recent date from among those rows. Next, the outer `=FILTER` selects only those rows from column C where column A has the most recent date among all rows with the same phase (as determined by the `=MAX`). Finally, if there's a tie (multiple phases are tied for most recent date), `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` returns only the first.

Functions used:

- [=FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [=MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=en)
- [=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.\


As you noted if multiple phases are tied for most recent, the first one is applied.\

Would it be possible to avoid this by adding an additional function( in Column E) that would exclude a specific text field. In this example, Most Recent Date IF Status is not equal 'Completed'\

here is a sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fBWQem9GFt0cMc1gGzgiWmCTESQLEumXgAqQg52DZz4/edit#gid=0

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to break ties by ignoring values in column E which have the value `Completed`. If that is correct, `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER($C$2:$C,$E$2:$E<>"Completed",$A$2:$A=MAX(FILTER($A$2:$A,$B$2:$B=B2))),1,1)` should do what you want. You can remove the `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` if Column E is guaranteed to prevent ties.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. From what I'm seeing it appears to work for the first set(rows 2-6, but gives an error when the formula continues to row 7 and beyond./ https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fBWQem9GFt0cMc1gGzgiWmCTESQLEumXgAqQg52DZz4/edit#gid=0

Comment: @AndrewScott `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFNA(FILTER($C$2:$C,$E$2:$E<>"Completed",$A$2:$A=MAX(FILTER($A$2:$A,$B$2:$B=$B7))),FILTER($C$2:$C,$A$2:$A=MAX(FILTER($A$2:$A,$B$2:$B=$B7)))),1,1)`

Comment: Thank you, this has helped get closer to the desired result. 
The problem I am trying to solve now is how to incorporate this formula to be able to be used on a column with potentially 1000s of rows of data to get the same result.